# How to use differentials to estimate the change in y?

Tags: calculus, approximation

Question:

Use differentials to estimate the change in y = - 1 / x as x moves from 3 to 3.3

I am just uncertain about how to approach this problem. I have tried to approximate the value of 3.3 and subtract the value of -1/3, which was an incorrect answer, but I might have messed up.

Comment: $dy=(1/x^2)dx$ , $\Delta y= (1/x^2)\Delta x$. $x=3, $$\Delta x=0.3$.OK?

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: J98.Pleasure:))